# Can't figure out why CSS changes the format of my images on smaller devices

Tags: css

I am scratching my head over an issue on [this WooCommerce-Site](http://taschenbyme.de/shop/). The product images look good and normal on a desktop, but get distorted and squeezed when sizing down to the size of an iPad or iPhone.

The thing is: I can't find out why. There are no media queries which could do that and the image format is fixed. What am I not seeing?

Thank you very much for taking a look.

Comment: Tested with Chrome developers tool, can't reproduce the problem. Can you attach a screenshot to show what's wrong?

Comment: Here you go: http://imgur.com/a/1moVl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer shortly: this is because style of your images is computed dynamically. Normally (on high resolution) images have following style:

```
.woocommerce .product-style-0 .image img {
    height: 203px;
    width: 274px;
}
```

This style causes obviously the image to have fixed width: 274px and fixed height 203px;

When you size down your browser (to small resollution) your element has style:

```
.woocommerce .product-style-0 .image, .woocommerce .product-style-0 .image img, .woocommerce .product-style-1 .image, .woocommerce .product-style-1 .image img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This makes the image to acquire 100% of the width of div container which it is located in. This efficiently takes 100% width of the screen on small resolution.

This is not a mistake though. You are basing your shop on woocommerce sollution and you acquired a template which is created according to [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) principle. Themes created using this idea makes sure the template has good usability on devices with small resolution.

As a consequence of using Responsice Web Design the theme you are using tries to make image big on small resolution so that it is well readable to the end user.

BTW: the filtering menu on the right-hand side is also hidden on small resolution in order not to consume precious space.

EDIT: And to make the answer straightforward.... If you are still wondering why the picture looks bad? Well when it get 100% width it gets "recalculated" to width of 392px (it is the widest form) but original image has only 274px, so the browser scales it up, thus loosing quality.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much, that was enlightening! So that means that I have to set the media queries for smaller screens to the same image ratio to make it work?

Comment: Genrally yes. This would be one of the solutions. Another can be to set fixed width/height for smaller screens (but this is not recommended because the image can be too big for some screens). Fixed aspect ratio (instead of "width 100%") seems like a good solution. You need to make sure your style `.woocommerce .product-style-0 .image, .woocommerce .product-style-0 .image img, .woocommerce .product-style-1 .image, .woocommerce .product-style-1 .image img` does not return `width: 100%` because this will obviously strech the image in uncontrolled manner.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please Accept it. Also, if you want to know how to keep fixed aspect ratio, search through stackoverflow  or post new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the units used to define the height and width of your images.

Let's say you made your images to take up 100 px inside the div of your page. This will remain the same size despite what platform you are using and will remain that same size. It will end up resizing awkwardly due to the mobile viewport and ultimately not look as planned.

You can fix this by using changing the units to either **percents** or **viewport height or widths** to **maintain the same image ratio** despite platforms.

Hope this helped!

Comment: His media queries set his image to 100% width, so that can't be it.